# Django model property: missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, django, django-models

**models.py**

```
class Thread(models.Model):

    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through="UserThread")

    @property
    def from_user(self, current_user):
        for u in self.users.all():
            if u.username != current_user.username:
                return u
            else:
                pass
```

My app contains 1 to 1 conversations, I coded this property to return the opposite user of the thread (e.g. the person I am speaking to). However, when I try to:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
t = Thread.objects.get(pk=1)
t.from_user(current_user=u)
```

I get the error that

> TypeError: from_user() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'current_user'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties can't take arguments.

But there is no reason to make this a property. You are calling it as a normal method. Remove the @property decorator.

Also note, your code is pretty inefficient. There's no need to query all the related users and iterate through. If you just want to get the first user that isn't current_user, then do so directly:

```
return self.users.exclude(username=current_user.username).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the @propery decorator

and you can call `t.from_user(u)`